# Error en router en laravel?

Tags: laravel, reactjs

Tengo un proyecto en laravel y react todo habia estado funcionando bien hasta que tuve que cambiar de disco duro reinstale todo para poder ejecutar el sitio nuevamente y ahora me lanza esta pantalla de error, alguna sugerencia? No se si se debera que no haya ejecutado algun comando con anterioridad y muestre esto, de ante mano agradezco los comentarios.

[image: Error de view en index]

Comment: Coloca mas detalle, tu archivo de rutas, que comandos ejecutaste, y otros que puedan ayudar

Comment: Como menciona @LeviArista, debes de incluir más detalle. Sería útil que coloques tu archivo de rutas, además del controlador y vista relacionada.

Comment: Prueba a borrar la caché de vistas. Podría ser un error de rutas relativas.